# How to use the field value as column name to get the value based on dynamically generated column name in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have below 4 tables as below:

**myTable1**:

[image]

**col_entry_detail**:

[image]

**quantity_value**:

[image]

**quantity**:

[image]

Code block to create tables is as below:

```
create table public.myTable1(id int,name varchar(50));
insert into public.myTable1 VALUES(1,'tv');
insert into public.myTable1 VALUES(2,'laptop');
insert into public.myTable1 VALUES(3,'desktop');

create table col_entry_detail(col_id int,col_name varchar);
insert into col_entry_detail(col_id,col_name) VALUES(1,'C_TV');
insert into col_entry_detail(col_id,col_name) VALUES(2,'C_LAPTOP');
insert into col_entry_detail(col_id,col_name) VALUES(3,'C_DESKTOP');

create table public.quantity_value(col_id int,value int,list_of_value int);
insert into public.quantity_value(col_id,value,list_of_value) VALUES(1,1001,10);
insert into public.quantity_value(col_id,value,list_of_value) VALUES(2,1002,15);
insert into public.quantity_value(col_id,value,list_of_value) VALUES(3,1003,40);
insert into public.quantity_value(col_id,value,list_of_value) VALUES(1,1004,15);
insert into public.quantity_value(col_id,value,list_of_value) VALUES(2,1005,70);
insert into public.quantity_value(col_id,value,list_of_value) VALUES(3,1006,40);
insert into public.quantity_value(col_id,value,list_of_value) VALUES(1,1007,60);

create table public.quantity(id int,C_TV int,C_LAPTOP int,C_DESKTOP int);
insert into public.quantity VALUES(101,1001,1002,1003);
insert into public.quantity VALUES(102,1004,1005,1006);
insert into public.quantity VALUES(103,1007,1002,1006);
```

Expected result should be as below:

[image]

Below is the select query which tried to fetch expected result from 4 tables:

```
select q.id as "Quantity_Id", qv.list_of_value, concat('q.C_',upper(t.name)) as "NAME"
from myTable1 t
join col_entry_detail ced on concat('C_',upper(t.name)) = ced.col_name
join quantity_value qv on qv.col_id = ced.col_id
join quantity q on concat('q.C_',upper(t.name)) = qv.value
where t.name ='tv'
```

So, how can I get the expected result?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't expect an answer to work on both.

Comment: i am trying it in Postgresql. Thanks for spending time to see this problem.

Comment: I am using Postgresql.

Comment: So if this is postgres, why is there a `mysql` tag on your question???

Comment: oh ok i think now it is removed. Please let me know how we can do it in postgresql?

Comment: Tip1: use meaningful names, so the links between tables becomes obvious. Tip 2: don't try finding a particular column but rather a particular ROW, so you can make simple joins instead of having to rely on a clumsy _dynamic query_.

Comment: This is not clumsy. I am using particular column because I want only those columns which must be present in Table : myTable1.  If you someone can resolve this problem then It will resolve my bigger problem that I am facing while migrating the data with similar kind of issue.

Comment: Why is the Quantity table a wide table? Why not just two (or maybe three) columns depending on what this table is trying to store? This complicates things. Products should not have their own columns. They should all be in one column with a product_type id.

Comment: yes you are right. but we have one tool which has this kind of db structure and now we are trying to migrate the data from that tool db architecture to new simplified db. let me know if you have any solution to this problem so that i can get my expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The joins you showed use literal values resulting from your concatenations and PostgreSQL will not try to interpret those values as column identifiers, unless you use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

You *can* do it without resorting to dynamic SQL as long as you know your column names up front, by using a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) to pick the right identifiers based on those literal texts [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KZhE1hwR)

```sql
select 
  q.id as "Quantity_Id", 
  qv.list_of_value, 
  concat('q.C_',upper(t.name)) as "NAME?",--again, this produces a literal 'q.C_TV' text
  CASE concat('q.C_',upper(t.name)) 
     WHEN 'q.C_TV' THEN q.C_TV
     WHEN 'q.C_LAPTOP' THEN q.C_LAPTOP
     WHEN 'q.C_DESKTOP' THEN q.C_DESKTOP 
  END AS "NAME"
from myTable1 t
join col_entry_detail ced on concat('C_',upper(t.name)) = ced.col_name
join quantity_value qv on qv.col_id = ced.col_id
join quantity q on qv.value = CASE concat('q.C_',upper(t.name)) 
  WHEN 'q.C_TV' THEN q.C_TV
  WHEN 'q.C_LAPTOP' THEN q.C_LAPTOP
  WHEN 'q.C_DESKTOP' THEN q.C_DESKTOP END
where t.name ='tv'
```

| Quantity_Id | list_of_value | NAME? | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 | q.C_TV | 1001 |
| 102 | 15 | q.C_TV | 1004 |
| 103 | 60 | q.C_TV | 1007 |

I agree with the comments that you likely need to rethink the table structure because this looks and feels wrong, it's pretty inconvenient to use and queries like this tend to perform poorly.

---

Dynamic SQL example, with [`format` placeholders](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) `%1$s` saying where to inject your dynamically created identifiers as-is and `%1$L` where to use them as text literals, at the core of it working pretty much exactly the way you intended: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9mjXk0BA)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quantities_lists_names(p_name text default null) 
  RETURNS TABLE (id int,
                 list_of_value int,
                 name int)
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $funcion_body$ 
  DECLARE v_name text;
  BEGIN
    FOR v_name IN SELECT DISTINCT m.name 
                  FROM public.myTable1 AS m
                  WHERE m.name=COALESCE(p_name,m.name)
    LOOP
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $dynamic_sql$
            select q.id as "Quantity_Id", qv.list_of_value, q.%1$s as "NAME"
            from myTable1 t
            join col_entry_detail ced on %1$L = ced.col_name
            join quantity_value qv on qv.col_id = ced.col_id
            join quantity q on q.%1$s = qv.value
            where t.name = $1
        $dynamic_sql$,
        concat('C_',upper(v_name)) ) 
     USING v_name;
  END LOOP;
END $funcion_body$;

SELECT * FROM quantities_lists_names('tv');
```

| id | list_of_value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10 | 1001 |
| 102 | 15 | 1004 |
| 103 | 60 | 1007 |

Called without arguments, it'll loop through all names in `mytable1`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM quantities_lists_names();
```

| id | list_of_value | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 40 | 1003 |
| 102 | 40 | 1006 |
| 103 | 40 | 1006 |
| 101 | 15 | 1002 |
| 102 | 70 | 1005 |
| 103 | 15 | 1002 |
| 101 | 10 | 1001 |
| 102 | 15 | 1004 |
| 103 | 60 | 1007 |

Comment: but if suppose we have 40 such columns then we have to hardcode 40 cases.Still need to think of some other solution where we don't need to hardcode case like:  WHEN 'q.C_DESKTOP' THEN q.C_DESKTOP

Comment: Thanks for this. I also want to get it for all the columns ie. tv,laptop,desktop. Then how i can do it as currently it is fetching only for tv then how i can get for all? Please help me in this also.

Comment: That's right and that's why there's dynamic SQL.

Comment: Suppose I am trying like this by removing the function parameters as below so that it can return for all product type from quantity table: CREATE FUNCTION quantities_lists_names()  Please let me know how i can do it
 
SELECT * FROM quantities_lists_names();

Comment: Trying something like this now:  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT(
        $dynamic_sql$
            select q.id as "Quantity_Id", qv.list_of_value, q.%t.name$s as "NAME"
            from myTable1 t
            join col_entry_detail ced on %t.name$L = ced.col_name
            join quantity_value qv on qv.col_id = ced.col_id
            join quantity q on q.%t.name$s = qv.value
            --where t.name = $1
        $dynamic_sql$
         );

Comment: it's giving error as: ERROR:  unrecognized format() type specifier "t"
HINT:  For a single "%" use "%%".
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function quantities_lists_names() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 22023

Comment: I want to get for all names whatever there in mytable1

Comment: The error message you got is pretty direct about what went wrong: that's just not how those placeholders work. `%1$s` means you want the first parameter given to `format()` after the $dynamic_sql$ text (in this case that's the result of `concat('C_',upper(p_name))` ), injected as is. `%2$s` would mean you want the second. `%1$L` means the first, but as a **L**iteral, e.g. text will be injected in single quotes, a number without any quotes. `%1$I` is for **I**dentifiers that get double quoted if necessary. It's all in the doc link in the answer where `format()` placeholders are explained.

Comment: I've updated the example to loop through the names if you don't specify one as an argument. Note that the stability of this approach relies heavily on the consistency of your model.